# Blending texture to draw translucent line

Tags: android, opengl-es, drawing, textures, opacity

I am trying to develop an android drawing app.In this app I am using texture to draw.
I want to draw translucent texture one over another to get continuous translucent line but I am only able to get this:[image]

As you can see in part B circular translucent textures appear one over other. I want line to appear as in part A.
I am adding information of texture drawing like `width,height,x&y coordinate in ArrayList` spriteArray.
The blending function used is- `gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_ONE, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);`
To set opacity of `texture-gl.glColor4f(1, 1, 1, opacityValue);`

I have also used `gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);`it does not work either.

Any help to solve this problem will be appreciated.
If you need more information please tell me.
drawFrame code:`enter code here`

```
gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_TEXTURE);
gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_ONE, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
gl.glColor4f(1, 1, 1, opacityValue);
for (int x = 0; x < GLSurfaceView.mSpriteArray.size(); x++) {
int
mTextureName=GLSurfaceView.mSpriteArray.get(x).textureName;
gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextureName);

// Draw using the DrawTexture extension.
((GL11Ext) gl).glDrawTexfOES(x, y, 0, width, height);
}
```